# Disable iPhone 4 data connection

Tags: iphone, ios, wifi, internet, cellular-data

Can I disable the data connection on my iPhone, but use the Wi-Fi as normal?

Answer (score 6):

Sure. In **Settings** > **General** > **Cellular** > disable **Cellular Data**

This will restrict all data to Wi-Fi

[image]

For more information, see [iOS: About the Cellular Data setting](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4203) from Apple Support

Answer (score 2):

Settings > General > Cellular > Cellular Data > Off.